# simultaneous variable assignation in pascal

Tags: variables, variable-assignment, pascal, simultaneous

I wish to do simultaneous variable assignment in Pascal.

As far as I know, it's not possible. Googling on the issue, I can see that many programming languages implement that, but I can't find how to do it in Pascal.

For example, in Python I can do this:

```
(x, y) = (y, x)
```

In Pascal, I need an additional variable to hold the value of x before it's removed, something like this:

```
bubble := x;
x := y;
y := bubble;
```

So, is there simultaneous assignment in Pascal, or should I rewrite the code to something like the bubble thing above?

I don't just have to do swaps; sometimes I have to do things like this:

```
(x,y) = (x+1,y+x)
```

Would it be ok to do it like the following?

```
old_x := x;
old_y := y;
x := x + 1; // maybe x := old_x + 1;
y := old_y + old_x;
```

Comment: The term you're looking for here is `swap` -- you want to swap the values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Although those four statements are OK, I think I'd just do it in two: `y := y + x; x := x + 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PASCAL does not contain a simultaneous variable assignment.

Nor does it contain a SWAP(X,Y) predefined procedure.

You have to do it yourself.

You might want to consider buying a copy of [[Jensen & Wirth]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/354006950X).  It is still the best reference manual available on the language.  If you are using one of the Borland PASCAL systems, use the manual that came with it: Borland made some incompatible changes, that nevertheless made the language significantly easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar at all with Pascal, but I can't find any special `swap` function that does what you want.

In any case, what you're doing is perfectly reasonable; any standard implementation of `swap` requires a temporary variable to hold one of the values being swapped. The only thing I would change in the code you have written above is to rename the variable to `temp`, to make it clear that the variable only exists temporarily for the purposes of the swap:

```
temp := x;
x := y;
y := temp;
```

**EDIT:** There's also nothing wrong with what you're doing when changing `x` and `y`. If you need to keep the old value as part of your calculations, it's perfectly fine to assign the old value to a variable and then use it.

Comment: thanks.. I edited the question to go beyond swaps.. should i do something like that?